# Unbalanced voltage accross full wave bridge rectifier

Tags: dual-supply

This an HiFi amplifier from end of 80's.
On the schematic below, I have asymmetrical voltages on the DC, +38 V and -40 V (on the leads of 1000 uF), instead +/-40 V, or +/-38 V -  now this is also the question which is correct.
The schematic lists the voltages keeping in mind old mains standard (220 V), however, even on 240 V the +/-35 V of the main (unregulated) supply, as well +/-30 V regulated (capacitance multiplier) are all OK.

The +/-38 V is going to predriver transistors and VAS of the amplifier.
Testing rectifier on board is inconclusive - the voltage drops across diodes of the bridge is not stable (starting from some 400 mV, and then falling gradually to some 170 mV, and this for all four diode tested.
The PS is reccaped (good quality 2200 uF Panasonic FC), and the bridge rectifier is UB-152 400 ns fast recovery type, but SIL old type with center +/- and lateral AC pins. Difficult to desolder.

Any idea what is going here? Diode problems?
Appreciate any input, except "put the scope..." since I have no scope, and no access to any such device :)[image]

Comment: What's the AC voltage from each winding?

Comment: _"I have no scope"_ For audio amplifier repairs and diagnostics, you're going to need one. At audio frequencies, even the cheapest USB ones will do the job.

Comment: `on the leads of 1000 uF` there are two pairs - mC4&5?

Comment: AC secondaries are 30V, very symmetrical, almost identical,  30,2V and 30,3V

Comment: @greaybeard: 
Yes, but to buy a scope just for this occasion - a bit too much I guess. But totally agree, it would be much more easy to spot what's going here.

Comment: What are you measuring with? If there is more load on other rail, it will have more ripple and e.g. a multimeter that measures just DC will see lower DC.

Comment: Are all voltages measured unloaded as in turned on but no audio playing?

Comment: "The schematic lists the voltages keeping in mind old mains standard (220 V), however, even on 240 V" The schematic says120v not 220V. Interestingly it indicates 50 Hz. CSA, UL suggests a N.A. market, so 120V at 60Hz is the target. mains voltage?

Comment: @winny: the amp is at idle, but speakers connceted, no signal, preamplifier separated (there is a swtich).
The main porblem started as hearable but subtle distortion after warming up - both channel, and some weaker bass. Troubleshoot, voltages as previously described

Comment: @russel: there are various primary wiring for other markets (not shpwed, but in service manual they exist), but the PS schematics is common for all of them. Ignore the left part of the schematics - htere is only one problem: all regulated and big output transistor votlages are as per schemtics, exept this one +/-38V from the capactiros C4/5, which is erroneous, and I cannot figure out why it is so.
This voltage is assymetrical, and the power amplifier is bridged, so symmetry ov the PS here is at must, to work properly.

Comment: @winny: measurements are made with DMM, some UNI-T true RMS

Comment: Right, with almost no loading, the AC ripple on the capacitors should be very small. Do you have significant distortion when playing just below clipping? I'm just thinking if the positive capacitor(s) are completely cooked so that you have AC ripple on it even when idling. An oscilloscope would be worth more than it costs for you here...

Comment: Nope, the capacitors are new, and the replaced ones were also whitin specs (although 36yo). But since it is fairly complicated to reach the board, once desoldered - I replaced all the capacitors with modern ones. 
With old capacitors, the voltage differences were 3V, now with new and doubled - the diffrence is above described 2V.

Comment: Amp distorts after some 10min worming up, and it is kind of distortion as if a weak FM station is listen to. Not linked to volume.

Comment: " The main porblem started as hearable but subtle distortion after warming up - both channel, and some weaker bass." Thisshould be mentioned in the original post @Erden

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the problem is with the power supply.

Completely disconnect the powersupply board from the rest of the amplifier. If the asymmetry dissappers, then the problem is not with the power supply, but somewhere in the power amplifier section.

EDIT: If the problem still exists, then the 30 volt regulators are suspect.

From the comments:

> The main porblem started as hearable but subtle distortion after warming up -

Along with the asymmetry, this suggests a damaged component in the audio amplifier that is causing excess current draw on one side of the power supply.

It could be a transistor, diode, capacitor, ...

Comment: OK, will do that. The amp came as described, I recapped, and changed several transistors affected by the notorious glue problem and corrosion, replaced using originals, resoldered suspicious joints, and still no result.

Comment: But - if, the disconnected PS wil still be assymetrical, what+s next to check? Could be the rectifier itself, but not so obvious (shortened diode, or so...)?

Comment: If the problem still exists, then the 30 volt regulators are suspect. @Erden

Comment: I don't know what "notorious glue" is but corrosion is a problem. Should have been mentioned in the question. You may need to do a complete teardown to eliminate all corrosion. @Erden

Comment: many home electronics made during the 70s, and 80s were using a glue for capacitor glueing to the board. But, during the years, air humidity and some glue component chemically react and some acidic chemical is generated, which in turn corrode besides capacitor legs, also anything came around the elements, causing numerous failures. Many forums of vintage audio are ful of the sentence "deadly glue"

Comment: Then the glue should be cleaned up as well. The glue and the corrosion could be the root cause causing other components to be damaged.@Erden

Comment: Sure, this is a rule - first clean glue, and then everything other. Already done.